# How to import a .mathcha-file into mathtcha.io?

Tags: backup, mathcha

In [mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor) it is possible to download the document as 
a `.mathcha`-file, as you can see in Figure_1.
However there seems to be no way to import this `.mathcha`-file again.
Even the "Menu" (see Figure_2) only offers you the possibility to export a LaTeX-file,
which by the way you can import, but it won’t be accepted,
because the exported Latex-code seems to be corrupted.

So I don't know how to create a restorable backup of my mathcha documents, 
when I am neither able to restore a `.mathcha`-file, nor I am able to export a working `.tex`-file.

---

[image: save_as_mathcha_file]
*Figure_1*

---

[image: mathcha_menu]
*Figure_2*

---

**Q:** Is there any way to import my `.mathcha`-file again, 
because if not, what are these files even good for?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have to get Mathcha Notebook to open the file.
The online version doesn't offer the function.[image]